# messages stuck in notification area

Tags: samsung, notifications, push-notifications, nexus

I have a Samsung J3 running Android 7.  I have received 2 notifications which seem to be stuck in the notification area, no way to get rid of them.
One is a Push Message saying that I've used 1.6Gb of my monthly traffic (coming from my carrier).  Which is somehow associated with the "Messages" app which came with the phone (can't tell who is the vendor on it) even though I set my texting app to "Messages" from Google.
The other one is from "Wifi Calling" and it notifies me that "Calls will be made over Wi-Fi". 
My previous phone was a Nexus and neither of these was a problem.  Wifi calling was a small icon at the top, not a whole notification message.  The push notifications about traffic would come in and be dismissed like any other message.  Is this a problem with Samsung notification app?  Can I replace it with the Nexus-style Google notification app?

For the comic relief: I was able to find others complaining about the stuck wifi calling notification and the advice to them was to disable wifi calling.

Comment: The second one might be what's called an [ongoing notification](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+"ongoing+notification) – and it's quite often asked how to get rid of them (I currently can't answer that, hence a comment with the hint only).

Comment: I should also mention that the damn traffic notification message sits on my lock screen all the time.  And when I dismiss it, it goes away for a bit and then comes back.

Answer (score 0):

The stuck push message about traffic  is solved.  I changed the default messaging app back to "Messages", then deleted the push notification and changed the default messaging application to "Messages" (yes, I am having too much fun with the fact that they are named the same).